# Load ICU Extension on Android sqlite to resolve LIKE lowercase issue

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, icu, sqlcipher

I have an Android app that is also used by Greek users, but I'm having an issue with some queries I'm making.
Essentially, the "like" functionality only works if I write Greek letters in uppercase.

After doing some research, it seems that the ICU extension support is missing.
What should I do? Can you provide any suggestions?